# Python + jetty?

Tags: python, maven, jetty

what would be the best way to start a jetty server from a python script? Currently, I am using just the command line to start it ( `mvn jetty:run` ). Unfortunately, I am not able to find any information on this topic.

Comment: Maybe your question has not enough details. What do you mean 'start a jetty server from a python script' specifically? You can just import os and use os.system('mvn jetty:run') in python, but I think perhaps this is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try it. I am still a beginner in python, I have never heard of import os. Will it be possible to end the process as well? Something like os.system('^C')?

Comment: Keyboard action is a little complicated, maybe you can find some information in Python document. os.system is very simple one, when you want advanced control on process, subprocess module is better.

Comment: I know this is an old question and you probably don't care too much about a solution anymore. Anyone still wishing to do this could either invoke maven using `subprocess` (preferred to os.system) or an alternative that could work if you are ok with writing java and python, is to use the [maven invoker api](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/index.html) and code up some java code that does what you want, package those into a jar and invoke them in python using subprocess. I didn't look into it, the former option might be easier but the later could give you more fine grained control.